# Googel Analytics 4 (GA4) Items how to View?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I am using ga4 to track my site it was working but my problem I create custom event using that I send data to GA4 using gtag() i get parameter and values but I cont. get and view the items.

```
            gtag("event", "add_to_cart", {
                currency: "USD",
                value: 7.77,
                items: [
                    {
                        item_id: "SKU_12345",
                        item_name: "Stan and Friends Tee",
                        affiliation: "Google Merchandise Store",
                        coupon: "SUMMER_FUN",
                        discount: 2.22,
                        index: 0,
                        item_brand: "Google",
                        item_category: "Apparel",
                        item_category2: "Adult",
                        item_category3: "Shirts",
                        item_category4: "Crew",
                        item_category5: "Short sleeve",
                        item_list_id: "related_products",
                        item_list_name: "Related Products",
                        item_variant: "green",
                        location_id: "ChIJIQBpAG2ahYAR_6128GcTUEo",
                        price: 9.99,
                        quantity: 1
                    }
                ]
            });

        }
```

ON the above code i can view the currency ,value. i can view the items :[]
[image]

Give me the solution to view the items from GA4